# symfony2 form date REQUIRED

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I make a form in symfony2 form. I add this field by builder:

```
 $builder->add('Incidenttime', 'date', array(
            'widget' => 'single_text',
            'label'=> 'EVENT DATE',
            'required' => true
        ));
```

An as you can see there is **REQUIRED => true**. But it is not required..

```
{{ form_label(form.Incidenttime) }}
 {{ form_widget(form.Incidenttime, { 'attr': {'class': 'datepicker'} }) }}
```

And this class **datepicker** is for choosing the date. 
Everything add fine to database but I want it to be REQUIRED.
What I done wrong?

Comment: Did you try to print {{ form_errors(form.Incidenttime) }}  ?
I'm quite sure form won't validate and will throw an error there.

Comment: Now I figured that when I delete this datepicker class it is required but what if I need this class?

Comment: The 'required' in the form builder is just adding a 'required' attribute, check by the browser in HTML5, but it *doesn't* 'require' it at a database level.

Comment: I need only if u dont fill this input to not save the form

Comment: Have you inspected the generated html? Is the 'required' attribute is affected to your field?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting the datepicker class while rendering the form, try setting it in the FormType class. Please try the code given below

```
$builder->add('Incidenttime', 'date', array(
        'widget' => 'single_text',
        'label'=> 'EVENT DATE',
        'attr' =>array(
           'class' => 'datepicker'
                    ) 
        'required' => true
    ));
```

Comment: No unfortunately still it is not required;/

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit late, but it might help someone else.

Some fields like date/datetime have no option "require".

You can check the what options are available in the documentation

http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/date.html

You should validate it manually on submit.